# Parsing error on salt docker-formula while using composeng

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I've run into an issue while using docker-formula's (https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/docker-formula) compose-ng. It crashes while parsing the image to install saying that whatever comes after the ":" is not an string (integer or float).

With the following pillar data obtained from the formula's pillar.example and slightly adapted to my needs:

```
docker:
  compose:
    registry-data:
      dvc: True
      image: registry:2
      container_name: &dvc 'registry-data'
      command: echo *dvc data volume container
      volumes:
        - /opt/docker-registry/data:/var/lib/registry
    registry:
      image: registry:2
      container_name: 'registry'
      restart: 'always'
      volumes_from:
        - 'registry-data'
      environment:
        REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: '/var/lib/registry'
      ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:5000:5000
    nginx:
      image: nginx:1.9
      restart: 'always'
      ports:
        - 5043:443
      links:
        - registry:registry
      volumes:
        - /etc/docker-registry/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - /etc/docker-registry/auth/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/auth
        - /etc/docker-registry/certs/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/certs
```

It ends up calling dockerio which seems to have a bug parsing the image tag throwing an exception. I managed to overcome it by modifying the source code of /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/dockerio.py

FROM

```
def _get_image_name(image, tag):
    if ':' not in image:
        # backward compatibility: name could be already tagged
        return ':'.join((image, tag))
    return image
```

TO:

```
def _get_image_name(image, tag):
    if ':' not in image:
        # backward compatibility: name could be already tagged
        return ':'.join((image, str(tag)))
    return image
```

Which I consider ugly and unmaintainable.

Versions:

- docker-py (1.6.0)
- salt-common 2015.8.3+ds-1
- salt-master 2015.8.3+ds-1
- salt-minion 2015.8.3+ds-1

The docker formula is obtained directly from gitfs in the salt-master config file.

So, can you point if  there's a mistake in my pillar or if it is something with dockerio or with this docker-formula and how it passes the values to dockerio or if I should call something else?

Still quite new on salt-docker. Let me know if further info is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the link to the formula you used? I assume you used https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/docker-formula. Please try to add quotes around your image name like in the example https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/docker-formula/blob/master/pillar.example

Comment: Yes, that was the formula. And the error was present using either single or double quotes around the image name.